# MARS MIPS Floating Point Exception Custom Handler Does Not Work - No Handler Works

Tags: exception, floating-point, mips, mars-simulator

I'm attempting to cause floating point exceptions (divide by zero, odd-register, etc.) and handle them in custom handlers. If I include handlers and step into the kernel code, (cause) and (epc) are 0x00000000. If I don't include a handler, the exception is correctly identified but I can't step into the kernel.

Tried all the combinations I could think of plus many hours searching but can find almost nothing about handling floating point exceptions in MARS. Not all that much for MIPS either.

```
.include "exceptions-s.asm"

    .data :
Pi : .double 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884
    .globl main
    .text
main :
    ldc1 $f5, Pi
```

Without custom handler, "line 18: Runtime exception at 0x00400004: first register must be even-numbered" but can't step into kernel code.

With custom handler, (custom) and (epc) are 0x00000000. Can step into kernel but results are useless.